# How to predict values using random forest model and multidplyr packages in parallel processing mode?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, pipe, random-forest, multidplyr

multidplyr package not parallelizing prediction process for random forest model

It runs when not processed parallely. here `[["finalModel"]]` is output from caret package using randomForest R package.

```
pred_dat <- dat_met_morph  %>% 
  predict(rf_model[["finalModel"]],.) %>%
  data.frame()
```

but not running when ran with multidplyr package

```
cluster <- new_cluster(15)
dat_met_morph <- dat_met_morph_df %>% partition(cluster)
cluster_library(cluster, "randomForest")
cluster_library(cluster, "caret")
cluster_copy(cluster, "rf_model")

pred_dat <- dat_met_morph  %>% 
  predict(rf_model[["finalModel"]],.) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Showing error `Error in predict.randomForest(rf_model[["finalModel"]], .) :  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`